# Number of Days issue in Code behind Calender

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
//DaysinLastMonth gives me the Days in April
//DaysinCurrentMonth gives me the Days in May



     public void RunCalender(int startOfCalender, int DaysinLastMonth,int 
                                                                DaysInCurrentMonth)
        {
            int value = 0, startOfCalender1 = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                HtmlTableRow tr = new HtmlTableRow();

                if (value == 0)
                   // StartOfCalender is the point where the Calender starts 
                   //from in the month display
                    startOfCalender1 = startOfCalender;
                else
                    startOfCalender1 = value;


                for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
                {
                    HtmlTableCell tc = new HtmlTableCell();
                    tc.BgColor = "#FAAFBE";
                    // tc.ColSpan = 1;
                    //tc.Attributes.Add("class", "rowA");
                    HtmlAnchor a = new HtmlAnchor();
                    a.HRef = "http://localhost:51955/Calender.aspx";

                    a.InnerHtml = startOfCalender1.ToString();

                    startOfCalender1 += 1;
                    if (startOfCalender1 == DaysinLastMonth + 1)
                    {
                        startOfCalender1 = 1;
                    }
                    value = startOfCalender1;
                    // Add the control to the TableCell
                    tc.Controls.Add(a);
                    // Add the TableCell to the TableRow
                    tr.Cells.Add(tc);
                }
                // Add the TableRow to the Table
                tbl.Rows.Add(tr);
            }
        }
```

**The problem is that the current month i.e is May is not showing 31 days as it should. Not able to think how to solve this issue**

[image]

Comment: Are you *sure* that the month it says it's displaying is correct? April & June both have 30 days.

Comment: How are you passing in those values ! !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is:

```
if (startOfCalender1 == DaysinLastMonth + 1)
```

In this example, DaysinLastMonth == Days in month of April == 30

So, the `if` statement above translates to:

```
if (startOfCalender1 == 31)
{
       startOfCalender1 = 1;
}
```

You want to use that logic when transitioning from April 30 to May 1.

You do not want to use this logic when transitioning from May 30 to May 31.

Comment: If you want to always display 6 rows of 7 days, then keep the two nested for loops.  Scrap everything you have regarding `startOfCalender1 `.  And next time, use a better variable name, like currentDayOfMonth or currentDate.  Don't use int to keep track of the current day of month, or else you will need to implement all of this calendar logic.  Instead, use DateTime, and add 1 day for each iteration of the inner loop.  The DateTime class will automatically know how to transition from one month to the next.

Comment: To add to the comment from @mbeckish - Use `var oneDay = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);` then you can do `currentDate += oneDay;` (if `currentDate` is of type `DateTime`)

Comment: i have done as you adviced @mbeckish how do i move to the next row continuing from where i left say a number 4

Comment: Move `CurrentDayOfMonth= startOfCalender;` to the top of the method, outside of the for loops.  The way you have it now, CurrentDayOfMonth resets at the start of every row.